# Joining characters in latex with no visible space between them

Tags: formatting

I would like to insert a character such that it has *no* width.

As a toy example consider `\rightarrow\leftarrow`
In the middle i would like to insert a (say) `\bullet`, but with *no* horizontal space.

I know that `\rightarrow\!\!\!\bullet\!\!\!\leftarrow` roughly does the job, but only for this particular character.

How do you do this construction in the general case?

Comment: I assume you want the character to actually have width (so you can see it), but so that it wont affect the text on either side? (In other words you want to add a character above the text?)

Comment: this question has several votes for closure on the grounds that it's not clear what is being asked.  the question is useful, and might benefit from a change in the title.  perhaps something like "joining characters in latex with no visible space between them"

Comment: Title changed according to suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The general solution is to use the optional width argument to `makebox`.

```
\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}
```

However if you do this

```
\(\leftarrow\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\rightarrow\)
```

you will still get little spaces at the ends of the arrows (because that's what you normally want).  So you may still need some negative space, unless you want to adjust the types of the math atoms themselves, like this

```
\(\mathord{\leftarrow}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\mathord{\rightarrow}\)
```

If you were trying to make the whole thing into a binary operator you might do something like this

```
\newcommand\spaceship{\ensuremath
   \mathbin{\mathord{\leftarrow}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\mathord{\rightarrow}}}

\(a\spaceship b\)
```

[image]

Note that the symbols do actually overlap, rather than abut.  This is more obvious if you turn the arrows round as you originally had in your example.

```
\newcommand\spider{\ensuremath
    \mathbin{{\rightarrow}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}{\leftarrow}}}

\( a\spaceship b\) and  \( c\spider d\)
```

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, the `\mathord` command isn't strictly necessary either; you can achieve the same effect simply by surrounding a sub-formula with braces, as shown in the second example.

Note also that the contents of a `makebox` are set in horizontal mode even when they are in the middle of a maths formula, hence the use of `\textbullet` rather than `\bullet`.

Comment: In this case you would have to make the arrows ords to see this working e.g. writing `\( {\rightarrow}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}{\leftarrow} \)`

Answer (score 19):

It mostly depends on the place where this should go. If a math symbol like the example you give is wanted, then

```
\[
\leftarrow\joinrel\mathrel{\bullet}\joinrel\rightarrow
\]
```

would be sufficient. I'm exploiting the fact that TeX inserts no space between consecutive **Rel** atoms; `\joinrel` is a small backspacing considered as a **Rel** atom (it's used when building long arrows by joining the arrow with minus signs). The whole construction, which probably you want to pack up in a macro, is considered as a relation symbol as far as the spacing around it is concerned. If you need it as a **Bin** atom, then use it as argument to `\mathbin`.

[image]

It's the same with the arrow pointing to the opposite directions:

```
\[
\rightarrow\joinrel\mathrel{\bullet}\joinrel\leftarrow
\]
```

[image]

In some cases a judgment on the amount of backing up is necessary. The definition of `\joinrel` is

```
\mathrel{\mkern -3mu}
```

and it's easy to adjust the amount based on this. For instance

```
\[
\rightarrow\mathrel{\mkern -2mu}\mathrel{\bullet}\mathrel{\mkern -2mu}\leftarrow
\]
```

would give

[image]

The relative shapes must be taken into account, so a general rule cannot be given.

Comment: Left and right have been swapped in relation to the question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I see! I'll add that.