# Thicker line for minus sign and plus sign

Tags: math-mode

Most of the times the minus sign in my documents is so thin and so short that I have a hard time seeing it on a printed copy. Is there a way to alter the thickness of the line for the minus sign (and, for matching purposes, the plus sign also)?

Comment: Do you plan to tell us anything at all about your existing documents which might enable us to advise you on possible modifications?

Comment: @Diegis :- The look and feel of a character is a decision of the font designer and the general advice is: if one doesn't like the look of a font, then use another font. In special cases it is also possible to exchange one glyph, but you should give more information about the font and your engine

Comment: If the minus sign is short,  I suspect you're not in math mode, and your ‘minus’ sign is actually a dash, as used to break words at the end of lines.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75987/a-bold-plus-symbol-in-math-mode

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm} % for the \boldsymbol
\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{+} $
$+ $
$\boldsymbol{-}$
$ - $
\newcommand{\pl}{\boldsymbol{+}}
$\pl $
\newcommand{\mi}{\boldsymbol{-} \mathrel{\mkern -16mu} \boldsymbol{-}}
$\mi $

% By increasing 'mu' you can shorten the minus sign.
\end{document}
```

[image: mathsymbols]

I used [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols) for obtaining thicker math symbols and I also used [Joining characters in latex with no visible space between them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145164/joining-characters-in-latex-with-no-visible-space-between-them/145172#145172) to extend the minus sign (although you can slightly tell it has been overlapped, which doesn't seem perfect). The new command definitions make it more convenient for you to use.

Comment: The `\mi` "minus" symbol is absurdly long, and looks like either an en-dash or even an em-dash. If one must bold-face the symbol, I'd stick with `$\boldsymbol{-}$`.

Comment: Many thanks for this Answer, it WORKS!

Comment: Now, I am using a variant: \newcommand{\pl}{\boldsymbol{+}\!} and \newcommand{\mi}{\boldsymbol{-}\!}}